# JxBrowser error as JavaScript error while calling "toFlex"

Tags: javascript, jxbrowser

Ie tried to run my application in JxBrowser,5.2.1 but application is not coming up, we are getting JS error in the logs as "JavaScript error while calling "toFlex" .Can you please help me how to make it work.

netscape.javascript.JSException: JavaScript error while calling "toFlex"

Comment: Please show us the code where the error occurs - The error alone isn't enough for us to help you.

Comment: The `netscape.javascript.JSException` class is not a part of the JxBrowser library and not used in it, this class is provided as a part of Java itself.
Therefore, it is hard to determine whether JxBrowser could be the cause of such issue having only the error message that you have provided.

Is it possible to provide a SSCCE that can be used to reproduce the same exception?